# Force bower to clone full git repository

Tags: javascript, git, bower, dependency-management

I'm using bower as my dependency manager, and I want to add a git repository as a dependency. I'm already aware of the fact I can do `bower install git@github.com:foo/bar.git`, however I need to *clone* the full directory because my dependency is on a source file of the repo.

The files that are missing when using bower are listed as ignored in the repository's bower.json file, the question is then: how can I force bower to clone them even though they're listed as ignored?

Comment: I don't think you can. You might have to git clone into the actual repo itself.

Comment: For now, I forked the repo, removed the line in the bower.json file and then changed my dependency on the forked repository.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just have the following to reference a git repo in your bower.json file(assuming you have an SSH key set up, just remove the +ssh if you don't):

```
"some-dependency-name": "git+ssh://<clone path in github>",
```

The clone path would be the link you copy/paste when you go to clone the repo, like "git@git.your-organization.com/path/to/gitfile.git"